# How to copy a particular file from multiple directories and rename with indexes using python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, shutil

I want to copy a specific file from different directories to another directory. Each of the directories has several files with the same extension. I want to copy one particular file from each directory to another folder and rename the file with indexes.
Here is an example of my current root directory tree.

```
root--Dir1--subDir1--subDir2
       |              |--x.bmp
       |              |--y.bmp
       |              |-t.txt
       Dir2--subDir1--subDir2
       |              |--x.bmp
       |              |--y.bmp
       |              |-t.txt
       Dir3--subDir1--subDir2
       |              |--x.bmp
       |              |--y.bmp
       |              |-t.txt
```

I want to copy only the ***x.bmp*** file to the other directory.
And my desired directory will be like given example tree below.

```
NEWDIR
|--x1.bmp
|--x2.bmp
|--x3.bmp
.
.
```

I wrote a sample code block by taking the help from other posts, but it is giving me error.
Here I posted code snippets and error.

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

root_dir = 'oldDir'
dest_dir = 'NewDir'
os.listdir(root_dir)
for folder in os.listdir(root_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        for subfolder in os.listdir(folder_path):
            subfolder_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder, subfolder)
            for subfolder2 in os.listdir(subfolder_path):
                subfolder2_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder, subfolder,subfolder2)
            for filename in os.listdir(subfolder2_path):
                if filename == 'X.bmp':
                
                    file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder, subfolder, subfolder2,filename)
                    for i in filename:
                        filename = 'X.bmp'%(i,)
                        dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
                        shutil.copy(file_path, dest_path)
                        print("Copied ", file_path, "to", dest_path)
```

The error messages that I got

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6448/526909518.py in <module>
     22                     #filename+=1
     23                     for i in filename:
---> 24                         filename = 'X.bmp'%(i,)
     25                         dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
     26                         shutil.copy(file_path, dest_path)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I got similar question in the stackoverflow, but answer did not help me. I appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` for finding the files you need. A sample is below

```
import glob, pathlib, shutil
root_dir = r"C:/drive/samples"
target_dir = pathlib.Path(r"C:/drive/samples/D2")
copy_files = list(glob.glob(f"{root_dir}/**/*.bmp",recursive=True))

index =1
for file in copy_files:
    file = pathlib.Path(file)
    target_file = target_dir / f"{file.stem}{index}{file.suffix}"
    shutil.copyfile(file, target_file)
    index+=1
```

May be there are more improvements to this. But this is one of the easy way to it,